# Как можно получить имя объекта вне созданного приложения?

Tags: c#, hook

Пытался найти информацию как можно это сделать, пока не  слишком успешно.

Вопрос звучит скорее всего некорректно поэтому примерно опишу что я пытаюсь сделать:

Я пытаюсь создать обычную апликуху, которая, будучи свернута в трей будет логировать имена объектов на которые я нажимаю мышкой. Например в отрытом Microsoft Word или PowerPoint:
Допустим я нажал на кнопку File, View или B (Bold). В логе мне нужно получить, в какой программе это было нажато (имя процесса, к примеру "WINWORD" меня вполне устроит), текст нажатого ("File", "View", "Bold") и время. Этой информации мне вполне хватит.

Пока что, ближайшее что мне удалось отыскать это MouseHook который позволяет получать... допустим, координаты вне созданного приложения... но этого мало. По идее, при клике мыши должен ловится handle и уже как-то обрабатываться дальше, но вот можно ли это реализовать в C#?

Comment: Ничего себе «обычная апликуха». Это хорошо, если прилозение написано на WinAPI (или основанных на ней WinForms), и объект с надписью является отдельным окном. А если WPF или другой безоконный фреймворк (Adobe Air вроде, не знаю насчёт Qt)?

Впрочем, покопайте в сторону Automation.

Comment: Скажу честно... не понял комментария. Если имеются ввиду ситуации windowless и иже с ними, то меня вполне устроят только те случаи где это название можно получить (опять же, пример Microsoft Word). В целом, мне вполне сойдет даже если это будет работать только в рамках Word/Point и иже с ними (апликуха требуется для исследования - куда узер клацает во время работы с Word, как часто и т.д).

Comment: @Олег Ясько: ну, возьмите в руки WinSpy++ или что-нибудь наподобие и посмотрите, как устроены контролы в вашей целевой версии Word'а. Если это WinAPI'шные контролы, можно обойтись малой кровью — тупо пошлите контролу сообщение WM_TEXT ([чтение по теме](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301438.aspx)). Если же Word переписали на WPF, отдельных контролов вам Spy не найдёт.

Comment: Чтобы это сделать, как я понимаю, для начала нужно получить конкретный контрол по нажатию мышки. Вот тут уже и начинается проблема, как заставить программу подхватить его по нажатию.

Comment: @Олег Ясько: А вы уж посмотрели, состоит окно Word'а из отдельных контролов, или оно цельное? В любом случае, [WinAPI `WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558.aspx) вам в помощь.